# How to make a login box that opens on hover over a menu item

Tags: css, web, html

I tried to make a small login box that opens when you hover over the login item in the menu bar, keeping in mind that the user doesn't have to go to another page to log in but I can't get it working.
Please help

```css
body {
  background-image: url("back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
  height: 1000px;
}

#head {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-main {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navigationmenu-parent {
  float: left;
}

.navigationmenu-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-line {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 155px;
  bottom: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px 1px #4d4d4d;
}

#logo-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#logo-image:hover {
  -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

.login-parent {
  float: right;
}

.login-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.login-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.login-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

#loginbox {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 132px;
  right: 90px;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
}

.loginchild:hover + .loginbox {
  visibility: visible;
}

#loginform {
  padding: 5px;
}

#loginelement {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>
  Le Meridian | A home away from home
</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="head">
      <img src="logo.png" id="logo-image" height="20%" width="20%">
      <ul id="nav_bar" class="navigationmenu-main">
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">A</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">B</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">C</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">D</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">E</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">F</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">G</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child">Sign Up</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child" id="trigger">Login ▼</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
          <div id="loginbox">
            <form id="loginform">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" name="loginsubmit" id="loginelement">
              <input type="checkbox" name="loggedin" id="loginelement"> Stay Signed In
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      dsa
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen when the user stops hovering over the menu-item?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what want you need to replace the hover code with this code:

```
.login-parent:hover  #loginbox {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And that keep the loginbox visible as long as the cursor is inside the `<li>`  tag with the class **.login-parent**.

if you do the hover on the div **loginchild** it will only show when you hover on that div.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
  height: 1000px;
}

#head {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-main {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navigationmenu-parent {
  float: left;
}

.navigationmenu-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-line {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 155px;
  bottom: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px 1px #4d4d4d;
}

#logo-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#logo-image:hover {
  -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

.login-parent {
  float: right;
}

.login-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.login-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.login-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

#loginbox {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 132px;
  right: 90px;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
}

.login-parent:hover  #loginbox {
  visibility: visible;
}

#loginform {
  padding: 5px;
}

#loginelement {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>
  Le Meridian | A home away from home
</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="head">
      <img src="logo.png" id="logo-image" height="20%" width="20%">
      <ul id="nav_bar" class="navigationmenu-main">
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">A</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">B</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">C</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">D</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">E</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">F</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">G</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child">Sign Up</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child" id="trigger">Login ▼</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
          <div id="loginbox">
            <form id="loginform">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" name="loginsubmit" id="loginelement">
              <input type="checkbox" name="loggedin" id="loginelement"> Stay Signed In
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      dsa
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some typos on class names. **Also the hover should be on the parent otherwise the box will not render properly.** It will flicker as soon as your mouse focus gets out of the child class.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("back.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
  height: 1000px;
}

#head {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-main {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navigationmenu-parent {
  float: left;
}

.navigationmenu-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navigationmenu-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigationmenu-line {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 155px;
  bottom: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px 1px #4d4d4d;
}

#logo-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#logo-image:hover {
  -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
}

.login-parent {
  float: right;
}

.login-child {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
}

.login-child:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.login-child:hover + .navigationmenu-line {
  width: 100%;
}

#loginbox {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 132px;
  right: 90px;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
}

.login-parent:hover  #loginbox {
  visibility: visible;
}

#loginform {
  padding: 5px;
}

#loginelement {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>
  Le Meridian | A home away from home
</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="head">
      <img src="logo.png" id="logo-image" height="20%" width="20%">
      <ul id="nav_bar" class="navigationmenu-main">
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">A</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">B</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">C</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">D</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">E</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">F</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navigationmenu-parent">
          <a href="" class="navigationmenu-child">G</a>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child">Sign Up</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="login-parent">
          <div class="login-child" id="trigger">Login ▼</div>
          <div class="navigationmenu-line">
          </div>
          <div id="loginbox">
            <form id="loginform">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="loginelement">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" name="loginsubmit" id="loginelement">
              <input type="checkbox" name="loggedin" id="loginelement"> Stay Signed In
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      dsa
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```